# Error in getSymbols, must use auto.assign=TRUE for multiple symbol requests

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm trying to write a program that would take a .csv file of stock symbols and test them against each other for things like cointegration. However, when I run the following code quatnmod gives me something about having to use auto.assign = TRUE for multiple symbol requests.

```
getprices<-function(sym){
  #get prices from last 7 years
  prices<-getSymbols(sym, from = Sys.Date() - (365*7), auto.assign=FALSE)
  #exract closing prices
  prices<-Cl(prices)

  return(prices)}


symbols1 <- c('TSN', 'MSFT')
symbols2 <- c('AAPL', 'NFLX')

container<-c()
addprices <- function(symbols1, symbols2){
   for (i in symbols1){
    for (g in symbols2){
      i<-getprices(i)
      g<-getprices(g)
      container <- i+g
      }
     }
    return(container)
    }
```

When I run addprices(symbols1, symbols2) I get this error:

```
Error in getSymbols(sym, from = Sys.Date() - (365 * 7), auto.assign = FALSE) : 
  must use auto.assign=TRUE for multiple Symbols requests
Calls: addprices -> getprices -> getSymbols
```

I know when I do this I should get that error, and I believe this is what the error is referring to:

```
getSymbols(sym, from = Sys.Date() - (365 * 7), auto.assign = FALSE)
```

However, what I'm doing isn't that, so what gives? Any advice? Is there a work around?

I googled this and there really weren't any relevant questions/answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're over-writing the iterator `i` inside the `g` for loop.  The first iteration of `g` works fine but `i` is no longer `symbols1[1]` in the second iteration... it's the output from `getprices(i)`.

Comment: @user1613119: if this answered your question, please consider marking it as such (as requested in the [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) section of the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)).